# Alexa Skill - How can I reprompt to my user that he has to use it again, if he is not saying stop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I want to publish my skill for Alexa. Nevertheless I have a problem with my sessions and reprompting it that the user can continue to play.

Here is the feedback:

"3. After the skill completes a task, the session remains open with no prompt to the user. The skill must close the session after fulfilling requests if it does not prompt the user for any input."

```
function getFactResponse(callback) {

//get random index from array of data
var index = getRandomInt(Object.keys(neverData).length -1);

// If we wanted to initialize the session to have some attributes we could add those here.
const sessionAttributes = {};

//Get card title from data
const cardTitle = neverData[index];

//Get output from data
const speechOutput = neverData[index];
// If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something that is not
// understood, they will be prompted again with this text.
const repromptText = 'Just say it again if you want to play' ;
const shouldEndSession = false;
callback(sessionAttributes,
    buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, 
shouldEndSession));
}
```

When I am putting shouldEndSession to true it does not work because Alexa is ending the session and the player has to start the skill again which should be not the case. I am hoping you can help me out:)

Can

Answer (score 2):

Given that the feedback specifies that the "session remains open with no prompt to the user", it suggests that in your response to the user, no question is being asked.

According to Amazon's [Detailed Certification Checklists](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing-for-a-custom-skill.html#session-management) the session should only be kept open if you're expecting user feedback:

> After every response that *asks the user a question*, the session remains open and the device waits for your response.

From experience, it is usually acceptable to prompt the user even without a question.

So if you want to keep the session open, a simple way to solve the problem might be to include your current reprompt in the speech output. This would alert the user to know that they can say something to start a new game. You would obviously then have to include another, slightly different, reprompt.